# Meaning of "gg" in indicating days

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

Giving a time estimate in days is always written in this way

```
10gg
```

Here "gg" refers to days, more precisely "giorni", but here there's only one g present.

My question is where "gg" is coming from?

Is it from the date format?

```
gg/MM/aaaa
```

Comment: No, not from the date format. Doubling is a way of expressing the plural. Sometimes the last character of an abbreviation is doubled, as in _pagg_, meaning pages. Sometimes Italians forget this rule, e.g., many people think that SS. stands for _santissimi_, while it simply stands for _santi_, saints.

Comment: This question currently has a comment that should be an answer and an answer that should be a comment.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, yes, that happens sometimes on StackExchange, and it's unfortunate. In my case it's not bad will, it's the dwindling time. A real answer should be checked and reasonably complete, and that takes time :-( Anyway, collaboration is welcome on StackExchange, so, if someone wants to write an answer building on my comment...

Comment: I have Swiss map from 1696, the river Maggia is written with one g. The town Maggia is written with one g.
In Gordevio there is a church, SS Gaicomo e Filipo, the church was build in the 1400 century and rebuild in 1700 century.
There are 2 tombs by the church entry, both tombs have the
name Gagioni. I know that village has Gaggioni with 2 gg.
I thought maybe the Latin language would write with 1 g, where the Italian language for pronunciation would use 2 gg.

Comment: @EnricoGiovanni: Welcome to Italian.SE! Unfortunately it's the other way round: often people in Northern Italy (and, of course, the Italian-speaking part of Switzerland) would forget how many *g*s the correct orthography has (because, as you're probably aware, geminate consonants disappeared in their regional language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vedi la tabella allegata per le abbreviazioni più comuni e il loro corrispettivo in inglese:

See the linked table for the most common abbreviations:

[Abbreviazioni](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/%7Engargano/corsi/corrisp/abbreviazioni.html):

giorno:

> - g. - giorno (d. -day)

giorni:

> - gg. - giorni (dd. -days)

La doppia g viene usata come plurale della singola g.
Vedi ad esempio

The double g is used as plural of the single g, for example:

> - Sig. -  Signore
> - Sigg. - Signori

Comment: Non vale solo per la g: "I proff. Tizio e Caio", "Le ss.vv. sono invitate", "Capitolo 3 e segg.".

Comment: I confirm. In Salerno there is an hospital that was merged with another one, and its full name is "Ospedali Riuniti S. Giovanni di Dio e Ruggi D'Aragona".
The label in front of the hospital abbreviated to "OO. RR. S. Giovanni di Dio e Ruggi D'aragona".

I don't live in Salerno anymore, but I assume it is still like that.